# How to override variable studentName given in class within changeName variable and new variable is used in userName when I call changeName method?

Tags: scala

```
class Person {
  val studentName = "Arpana"

  def changeName(id:String, name:String) ={
  val studentName = name
  useName(id)
  }
  def useName(id:String) = {
    println(s"use name is $id, by $studentName")
  }
}

object Person {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    (new Person).changeName("2", "Shubham")
  }
}
```

I don't want to use var in code, can we do it by keywords, I tried with keywords like super, protected, private, final but didn't work.
In actual I want to apply this in the below code.

```
abstract class BaseRepository[T <: BaseModel : ClassTag : StriveSerializer] {
  self: BaseConnection =>
  val tableName: String = implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass.getSimpleName
  private val serializer = implicitly[StriveSerializer[T]]
  private def executeInserts(query: String): Future[Boolean] = Future {
    val preparedStatement = self.connection.prepareStatement(query)
    preparedStatement.execute()
  }
  def exist(id: String, name: String): Future[Boolean] = {
    val tableName = name
    val promise = Promise[Boolean]
    queryById(id).onComplete {
      case Success(_) => promise.success(true)
      case Failure(ex) => promise.failure(ex)
    }
    promise.future
  }

  def queryById(id: String): Future[T] = {
    val getSql = s"SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE id == $id;"
    executeReads(getSql).map(serializer.fromResultSet)
  }
}
```

I want when i call exist function then table name given in exist function override in queryById method table name .

Comment: I want to mutate something but I do not want to make it mutable, doesn't make much sense. - Also, not sure what do you mean by keyword? What would `super` do here? It seems you do not understand how oop work and are yous typing random things, it would be good to study a bit more before coding. - What you want to do is not possible, the code is bad designed as simple as that. Your `queryById` function should accept the `tableName` as a parameter and maybe use a default value if you do not want to specify it always.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bit of mix of Java and Scala style. I tried to refactor a bit assuming the intention behind the code. Try and see if this achieves what you want to do:

```
class Person(_id: String, _studentName: String) {
  private val id: String = _id
  private val studentName: String = _studentName

  def useName() = {
    println(s"use name is $id, by $studentName")
  }
}

object Person extends App {
  new Person("2", "Shubham").useName()
}
```

Comment: Please, see once question is editted. it will be great if you can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `case class` For Model

```
case class Student(id:String,name:String)

def changeId(student:Student, newId:String): Student ={
  student.copy(id=newId)
}

val s1 = Student("1","A")
val newS1 = changeId(s1,"2")
```

I think it okay to use mutable in a `class`
e.g.

```
class MySuperService{

  var lastHeartbeat: Option[Timestamp] = None

  def setLastHeartbeat(ts:Timestamp): Unit ={
    lastHeartbeat = Some(ts)
  }
}

val mss1 = new MySuperService()
mss1.setLastHeartbeat(???)
```